# Why isn't this working? - for each line in text file get file contents & check if it equals something specific

Tags: php

```
 <?php
error_reporting(0);
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
    array(
        'timeout' => 5,
    )
));

$handle = fopen("ist.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
$check = file_get_contents($line, false, $ctx);
if ($check == 'hi.') {

echo $line;

echo 'yay';

} else {

echo 'ney';

echo $line;

}

}
} else {

echo 'error reading file';

}

fclose($handle);

?>
```

It worked when I only just did 1 url.

Basically what it's doing is printing out neyhttp://mysite/hi.txt

and no the line does not have any spaces or anything.

Comment: fgets() - Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, __or a newline (which is included in the return value)__, or an EOF (whichever comes first)..... my emphasis

Comment: Can you provide us with a little more context? What's the content of the file that is being read and what should be the output?

Comment: @mmgross Basically website links are being read e.g. (1 line being http://hello.net/hi.txt another being http://blahblah.blah/123.txt) etc, the script is supposed to check if the website's whole content equals "hi." Now i've tried this with legitimate links 2 & 1 bad one and the output was ney (not working) on all 3 of them.

Comment: I think your comparison `$check == 'hi.'` is the problem. `$check` may be somehow terminated (e.g. with a newline). And maybe you should check, if what Mark Baker said is a problem as well: `$line` is most probably terminated by a newline, that may interfere with `file_get_contents`

Comment: @mmgross how would it be? the first line didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

`File_get_contents` gives source of the page. To check the content use:

```
if (stripos(strtolower($check), 'hi.') !== false) {

}
```